# Print php array with my own devision

Tags: php, android, arrays, json, pdo

Hey I have a php code that needs to read from table all of its content and print it, I want it to print it in an organized way so I can use it in my android app something like: id|name|id|name|id|name , but I don't find a way to do this just like this so far I tried the implode() method and json print, the json printing me like that:

```
[ { "id": 1, "name": "jack" }, { "id": 2, "name": "brian" }, { "id": 3, "name": "johnny" } ]
```

and the code is:

```
    $stmt = $db->query('SELECT * FROM sample');
$results = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
echo json_encode($results, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
```

how can I make it print the way I want?

Comment: What actually you want to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

```
$results = '';
foreach (stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) as $row)
{
    $results .= $row['id']."|".$row['name']."|";
}
echo substr($results, 0, -1)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$stmt = $db->query('SELECT * FROM sample');    
$results = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

then

```
$out = ''
if (is_array($results) && count($results) > 0) 
{
  foreach ($results as $sqlRow) 
  {
    $out .= $sqlRow['id']."|".$sqlRow['name']."|";
  }

  $out = substr($out, 0, -1);
}
echo $out;
```

but JSON is either to work with, FYI

Answer (score 0):

Actually you don't need to transform. You just have to use some networking to fetch this json in android and after that you can use https://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/package-summary.html

to get your desired data in desired views in android :)